# Формула полета пули в 2d игре

Tags: c, разработка-игр, sdl

Пишу небольшой 2D шутер. Возникла проблема с просчетом траектории полета пули. если в кратце: персонаж, который стреляет находится в центре экрана ( вид сверху), нам известен угол, на который повернут персонаж, начальная позиция пули так же центр экрана соответственно. Вот как я это пытался сделать:

```
phy->ownbullets[i].cX += cos(da) * .5 ;
phy->ownbullets[i].cY += sin(da) * .5 ;
```

где .5 - скорость полета, da - угол, но все равно траектория хаотична. В чем может быть проблема?

Запись экрана - http://rgho.st/6HkZk2Tpy

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под хаотичностью?

Comment: Могли бы Вы приложить скрин или гифку?

Comment: @hedgehogues http://rgho.st/6HkZk2Tpy

Comment: Могли бы Вы привести больше кода?

Comment: я вот руками ввел phy->ownbullets[i].cX += cos(90) * .5 ;phy->ownbullets[i].cY += sin(90) * .5 ; 90 градусов, все равно пуля летит куда-то на 35

Comment: Функции `sin` и `cos` принимают угол в радианах, а Вы градусы передаёте, возможно в этом ошибка? Попробуйте `cos(90 * 3,14159 / 180)`

Comment: Почему Вы суммируете? Не лучше ли заменить `+=` на `=`?

Comment: @Alexshev92 Да, большое спасибо. В этом и была ошибка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функции `sin` и `cos` принимают значения в радианах. Если значения угла в градусах, то необходимо перевести их в радианы (умножить на число Пи и разделить на 180 градусов):

```
const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
phy->ownbullets[i].cX += cos(da * pi / 180) * .5 ;
phy->ownbullets[i].cY += sin(da * pi / 180) * .5 ;
```